# Javascript Inheritance - this.element is undefined in subclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I'm trying to set up a parent class that extends a subclass, but whenever I attempt to reference this.element in the subclass when called from the superclass, it's undefined.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
$.widget("ui.testSuper", $.extend({}, $.ui.testSub.prototype, 
{
    _init: function ()
    {
        $.ui.testSub.prototype._init();
    },
...
}));

$.widget("ui.testSub", $.ui.mouse,
{
    _init: function ()
    {
        this.element.addClass("some-class");
    },
...
});

$('#some-element').testSub({ }); // this works fine

$('#some-element').testSuper({ }); // this.element is undefined
```

Comment: Probably because of jQuery doing black magic somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend `$.ui.testSub` it doesn't exists at those point. All you need to do is to swap those two blocks of code:

```
//Should be first
$.widget("ui.testSub", $.ui.mouse,
{
    _init: function ()
    {
        this.element.addClass("some-class");
    },
...
});

$.widget("ui.testSuper", $.extend({}, $.ui.testSub.prototype, 
{
    _init: function ()
    {
        $.ui.testSub.prototype._init();
    },
...
}));

$('#some-element').testSub({ }); // this works fine

$('#some-element').testSuper({ }); // then it will work fine as well
```

See live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/46D8T/11/)

**UPDATE**

I got what you're saying. You need to call base method like this

```
$.ui.testSub.prototype._init.call(this);
```

So you will not loose the context of your element. Example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/46D8T/15/)

Comment: A valid point on the ordering, I didn't consider that when I posted the question.  But the root problem remains - you can see it if you actually add the element I'm trying to call the widget on.

http://jsfiddle.net/46D8T/12/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using $.extend is the way to go here.

Here's how I typically extend jQuery UI widgets:

```
$.widget('ui.testSuper', $.ui.testSub {
    _create: function() {
        $.ui.testSub.prototype._create.call(this);
    }
});
```

I see you are using _init, so must be using an older version of jQuery UI.